# Trouble with Macro Updating Table Cells in MS Word Header

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-automation

I'm working on a macro that will update the cells of a table in an MS Word header according to values I'm storing in excel. Hoping this will speed up the process of manually updating the headers containing the project phase and due date in the 100+ word docs I'm working with. I know very little about VBA but cobbled this code together and hoping someone who knows what they're doing could point me in the right direction to get this code working. Happy to provide more information if it helps. Thanks!

**Update:** Thanks to all who have provided suggestions for getting this to work - still getting an error for some reason. Having some trouble recognizing and editing the table in the header.

I'm getting Error 5941 on this line - Requested member of the collection does not exist

```
With oWordDoc.Sections(1)...
```

Here's what I've got:

```
Sub UpdateSpecHeaders()
Dim oWordApp As Object
Dim oWordDoc As Object
Dim sFolder As String, strFilePattern As String
Dim strFileName As String, sFileName As String

    '> Folder containing files to update
sFolder = Range("A20").Value

    '> Identify file extension to search for
strFilePattern = "*.doc"

'> Establish a Word application object
On Error Resume Next
Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

oWordApp.Visible = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'> Loop through the folder to get the word files
strFileName = Dir$(sFolder & strFilePattern)
Do Until strFileName = ""
    sFileName = sFolder & strFileName
    

    '> Open the word doc
    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(sFileName)
           
    '> Update Header
              
    With oWordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables(1).Range
    
            .Cells(Row:=3, Column:=1).Text = Range("A3").Value
            .Cells(Row:=3, Column:=2).Text = Range("B3").Value
    End With
                
    '> Save and close the file
           
    oWordDoc.SaveAs Filename:=oWordDoc.Name
    oWordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    '> Find next file
    strFileName = Dir$()
Loop

'> Quit and clean up
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
oWordApp.Quit

Set oWordDoc = Nothing
Set oWordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using `ActiveDocument` when `oWordDoc` already points to the document you want to modify?

Comment: That's a great question - I'm not sure. I can delete those out, do you think that's playing into the error with the code? Very little VBA experience here

Comment: If there is more than one document open, then yes.

Comment: Ah I see, my intention was to have one document open at a time, opening, updating, saving and closing before moving onto the next

Comment: It aways pays to be specific, so change `ActiveDocument` to `oWordDoc`. I would also add a check to ensure that there are at least 2 tables in the header, e.g. `If oWordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables.Count > 1 Then`

Comment: You might want to put the information in the body of your document and use a StyleRef field to put in the headers. You might also want to store it as a Document Variable and use a DocVariable field in the headers. Either would likely be simpler that editing the headers.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?69738-Macro-to-Edit-Contents-of-in-Table-in-Word-Header. Please review etiquette at: https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: As you are the only one with the document(s) there is only so much we can do to help you. It is down to you to determine where in the document the table you want to modify is located. You need to determine whether the table really is in a header, and, if so, which section and which of the three header types it's contained in.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting Error 424 - Object Required on this line

```
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)...
```

That is because you run the VBA macro from Excel where shorthand properties are `ActiveWorksheet`, `ActiveWorkbook` and etc. But the `ActiveDocument` property makes sense only when you run the code in Word. So, the following code should be changed:

```
  '> Update Fields
    oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
    
    
    '> Update Header
    
        With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables(2)
        .Cell(Row:=3, Column:=1).Text = Range("A3").Value
        .Cell(Row:=3, Column:=2).Text = Range("B3").Value
            
        End With
```

It should look like that:

```
  '> Update Fields
    oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
    
    
    '> Update Header
    
        With oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables(2)
        .Cell(Row:=3, Column:=1).Text = Range("A3").Value
        .Cell(Row:=3, Column:=2).Text = Range("B3").Value
            
        End With
```

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the code to have the active document within the Word app but still am receiving the error "requested member of the collection does not exist". It looks like its recognizing the Word doc correctly but not seeing the table in the header. Ran a test to count the tables in the header and it said there weren't any for some reason.

Comment: That is another issue.

Comment: Ah I see, quickly getting in over my head here!

Comment: I'd recommend posting separate issue in a new thread so users could distinguish between different issues.