# Editing MS Word Tables within Headers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a macro to edit the cells of a table within a MS Word header, the headers only contain a table with the same information in all the documents I'm working with. I have the text with which I'd like to overwrite the existing text stored in an Excel file and hope to be able to cycle through all of the word docs within a specified folder, edit the headers, save, close and repeat. My VBA experience is slim to none but I've cobbled together some code based upon similar forum posts I've found. Thank you to those who've helped so far, creating a new question to address some of the new and different errors I'm receiving after incorporating recommended code edits.

I'm getting an error I can't seem to understand or fix on the line below: Error 5941 - Requested member of the collection does not exist. It seems like once the Word doc is opened, the header is not being recognized but I'm not entirely sure of the issue.

```
With oWordDoc.Sections(1)...
```

Any help or insight would be much appreciated as this is all quite new to me. Thanks!

Code so far:

```
Sub UpdateSpecHeaders()
Dim oWordApp As Object
Dim oWordDoc As Object
Dim sFolder As String, strFilePattern As String
Dim strFileName As String, sFileName As String

'> Folder containing files to update
sFolder = Range("A20").Value

'> Identify file extension to search for
strFilePattern = "*.doc"

'> Establish a Word application object
On Error Resume Next
Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

oWordApp.Visible = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'> Loop through the folder to get the word files
strFileName = Dir$(sFolder & strFilePattern)
Do Until strFileName = ""
    sFileName = sFolder & strFileName 

    '> Open the word doc
    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(sFileName)
           
    '> Update Header     
    With oWordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables(1).Range
            .Cells(Row:=3, Column:=1).Text = Range("A3").Value
            .Cells(Row:=3, Column:=2).Text = Range("B3").Value
    End With
      
    '> Save and close the file
    oWordDoc.SaveAs Filename:=oWordDoc.Name
    oWordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    '> Find next file
    strFileName = Dir$()
Loop

'> Quit and clean up
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
oWordApp.Quit

Set oWordDoc = Nothing
Set oWordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This is identical to your previous question [Trouble with Macro Updating Table Cells in MS Word Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489286/trouble-with-macro-updating-table-cells-in-ms-word-header)

Comment: Hi there - sorry about that. I made some updates and someone recommended I create a new post to address the different errors I was receiving after incorporating recommended changes and help distinguish between problems before and problems now. Thank you for the guidance along the way though, its been really helpful